# Relations and Active Query in Yii2?

Tags: php, mysql, activerecord, yii, yii2

I have 2 tables:

**Auto**

```
id (pk) int

name varchar100

color int
```

**AutoComparison**

```
auto1_id

auto2_id

status
```

***Where:***

```
(*status - 
id 0 new

id 1 old

id 2 broken)
```

I need to select all cars whose status (id 2 "broken") and count the number of them.

The question that I need to change in the model and insert into the view file, in order to display the number of broken auto's. (Framework Yii2)

Comment: $count = \Yii::$app->db->createCommand("
    SELECT COUNT(*) FROM AutoComparison WHERE status=2"
)
->queryScalar(); //Count

$dataProvider = \Yii::$app->db->createCommand("
    SELECT COUNT(*) FROM AutoComparison WHERE status=2"
)
->queryAll(); //All record

foreach ($dataProvider as $model) {
    echo 'Car name: ' . $model->auto->name;
    echo '<br/>';
    echo 'Car color: ' . $model->auto->color;
}

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can access your relations by calling the relation as you would a property of the model.

To count:

```
$count = AutoComparison::find()->where('status = 2')->count();
```

To select the models:

```
$models = AutoComparison::find()->where('status = 2')->all();
```

Show the names and colors of the broken cars:

```
foreach ($models as $model) {
    echo 'Car name: ' . $model->auto->name;
    echo '<br/>';
    echo 'Car color: ' . $model->auto->color;
}
```